# Adding a Disk and Using Divergence theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-theorem

Let $S_1$ be the lateral surface of $x^2 + y^2 \leq 4$ for $-3 \leq z \leq 3$, and $S_2$ be the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + (z-3)^2 = 4$. Assuming $S$ to be $S_1 \cup S_2$ and $\hat{N}$ to be unit outward normal on $S$, for a given vector field $\overrightarrow{F}$ for which $div(\overrightarrow{F}) = 0$, how can we evaluate $\iint_S\overrightarrow{F}.\hat{N}dS$ using divergence theorem?

So the solution offers adding a disk with equation $x^2 + y^2 \leq 4$ for $z = -3$, which encloses the region and then divergence theorem can be used. But what about the half spherical surface which lies inside the cylindrical surface? By adding this disk, don't we exclude the flux passing through this inner half-spherical surface inside the region?

By the way, the answer suggested is $\iint_S\overrightarrow{F}.\hat{N}dS = - \iint_{S'}\overrightarrow{F}.(-\hat{k})dS$, where $S'$ represents the disk.

Comment: The question is badly written. I think they mean flux of cylindrical lateral surface between $-3 \leq z \leq 3$ with hemispherical top.   If the divergence of the vector field is zero then yes that flux will be equal to $- \iint_{S'} \overrightarrow{F}.(-\hat{k}) \ dS$ where $S'$ is the disk at $z=-3$.

Comment: @MathLover thanks, I guess that's it.